# MS Azure / Not able to ping VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, ping

I have deployed a VM in Ms Azure and created a new "`Allow ICMP`" rule to allow ping to newly created VM on Azure portal.

I have also added a FW rule on VM to allow incoming ICMP traffic.
I was able to ping VM from my local laptop after above 2 steps.

Now, For testing, I have updated FW rule on VM to deny incoming traffic, which has stopped ping from my local laptop.

Problem is,

> Ping is not working after re-enabling FW rule on VM to allow incoming
> ICMP traffic.

Why this is the case here? Do I need to delete and re-create ICMP rule on Azure portal? OR Do I need to redeploy my VM?

Answer (score 3):

I tried the same in my environment created virtual machine and allowed ICMP Nsg like below:

[image]

Ping requests to the virtual machine is supported and the firewall rule can be modified to permit incoming ICMP traffic. However, sometimes modifications to firewall rules might not be immediately or correctly implemented.

When I ping, it shows the request timed out.

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/knqRHcC.png)]

***Go to Remote desktop -> search bar, type Windows Firewall with Advanced Security -> inbound security -> Enabled ICMPv4 -> Apply and ok like below:***

[image]

[image]

Enabled ICMP like below:

[image]

Now when I tried to ping, it pings successfully like below:
[image]

I tried to deny incoming traffic and after re-enabling FW rule on VM to allow incoming ICMP traffic ping work successfully like below:

[image]

If still issue persists,

- Check whether the rule is enabled and allowing traffic on the correct port so that the firewall rule setting on the virtual machine is set up properly to allow incoming ICMP traffic. Verify the rule is active and the modifications have been saved.
- Ensure that NSG is associated with your VM to allow traffic. Make sure no conflicting or overriding rules that could be blocking the traffic. You can also try to disable and re-enable the rule or redeploy the VM.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [what @Imran's answer covers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76331632/159145), I discovered that in a new VM (WS2022 Azure Edition) I provisioned a couple of hours ago, the Windows Firewall rules for ICMP Ping on Private+Public networks default to *Local subnet*.

So here's the full steps I needed to do:

1. In the Azure Portal, I granted myself an Allow rule in the VM' Network Settings.

   - Ensure "Protocol" is "Any" or "ICMP"
   - Ensure the source IP address actually matches my (workstation)'s public IP. If you're double-NAT'd then you might have the wrong public IP.
   - Ensure `*` is being used for both Source and Destination port-ranges.
2. In the VM (via RPD), I explicitly enabled all *Core Networking Diagnostics - ICMP Echo Request (ICMPvN-In)* rules in the Windows Firewall MMC (now branded *Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security*)
3. Verify that the VM's local network profile (Domain/Private/Public) is correct.
4. For each of those ICMP Echo request rules:

   - Open their Properties dialog and go to the *Scope* tab and verify "Remote IP addresses" is "Any IP address" and *not* the "These IP addresses: Local subnet".

[image]

---

**So this is what it should look like:**

[image]